# Inject system variable to module.exports in vue js

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I'm trying to inject a system variable that I'll initialise in my container to my vue js api.
in my api.js I use the variable this way:

```
const BASE_URL = process.env.CORE_URL
```

and I load my configuration via wabpack:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     'process.env': config.dev.env
  }),
```

then I manage my variables in js dev.env.js using module.export

```
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
   NODE_ENV: '"development"',
   API_URL: '"@@API_URL@@"',
})
```

I'm unable to inject the API_URL that I'll set in my container to the dev.env.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way. I had to create to shell script that during build create a dev.env.js out of dev.env.template.js and replace on the variables starting with @@ with the value on dev.env.js. the dev.env.js is added during build to dist folder on the container.